# Manually adding SANE device address to work with GUI

Tags: opensuse, printing, scanner, sane

I have a Samsung M2070W MFP and I want to make scanning over network functional in GUI programs such as simple-scan. I used the official driver installer (SANE driver `smpf`) and scanning over USB worked flawlessly with auto-detection.

However, auto-detection over network is not working. I managed to get it to work by using manually `scanimage -d "smfp:net;xx.xx.xx.xx"`, but I would like to manually add this address somewhere for all applications that work with SANE to see.

Answer (score 1):

After more research I finally found a solution, but it is not ideal.

You can force use the device with simple-scan like this: `simple-scan "smfp:net;xx.xx.xx.xx"` or with skanlite: `skanlite --device "smfp:net;xx.xx.xx.xx"`.